# SQL: Unable to find a join or union to produce the following table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

A Pupil table with { ID, LastName}

a Subject Table with {ID, SubjectName}

and a Report Table with {ID, PupilID, SubjectID, Grade}

There is a one-to-many relationship between Pupil and Report Tables, and Subject and Report Tables.

I want to generate a table like this for say subjectID  = 1

```
Pupil.ID  Pupil.LastName  SubjectID Grade

1 --------------Smith ---------- 1 ------------B
2 --------------Jones ---------- 1 ------------NULL
3 -------------Weston ----------1 ------------NULL    
4 -------------Knightly ---------1 -----------A
```

The problem is that the Report table would contain just 2 entries for subject 1:

```
PupilID  SubjectID  Grade

----1------- 1 ----------- B  
----4------- 1 ----------- A
```

Left joins don't seem to work since there are only 2 entries in the report table for subject 1

SAMPLE DATA

```
{Pupil Table}

ID LastName    
1 ...Smith    
2 ...Jones    
3 ...Weston    
4 ...Knightly

{Subject Table}

ID SubjectName    
1 ....Maths    
2 ....Physics    
3 ....Chemistry

{Report Table}

ID PupilID SubjectID Grade    
1 .......1 ..........1 ..........B    
2 .......4 ..........1 ..........A
```

When I do a search on SubjectID = 1 I want the table:

Pupil.ID  .......Pupil.LastName  ........SubjectID ...........Grade

```
1 --------------Smith ---------- 1 ------------B
2 --------------Jones ---------- 1 ------------NULL
3 -------------Weston ----------1 ------------NULL
4 -------------Knightly ---------1 -----------A
```

Comment: Which database client are you using?

Comment: Access (mdb format)

Comment: Provide some sample data from all three of your tables.

Comment: Added sample data

Comment: See updated answer. I have it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access doesn't do subqueries very easily, so everything gets crammed into the FROM clause with a series of wrapped parentheses. Based on your sample data and my fighting Access to stop being unnecessarily difficult, I came up with this:

```
SELECT ps.Pupil_ID, ps.LastName, ps.Subject_ID, r.Grade 
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID AS Pupil_ID, LastName FROM Pupil) p, 
         (SELECT DISTINCT ID AS Subject_ID FROM Subject)) ps
     LEFT JOIN REPORT r ON r.PupilID = ps.Pupil_ID AND r.SubjectID = ps.Subject_ID
ORDER BY Pupil_ID, Subject_ID;
```

The subquery "ps" is a cartesian join of the Pupil and Subject table views that I specified. At this point, your query would look like this:

```
(LastName column not shown for clarity)

StudentID|SubjectID
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         2
2         3
3         1
3         2
3         3
```

Now, using that Cartesian join subquery (pupilstudent -> ps), I use a LEFT JOIN to assign the Report table to each unique student's ID and subject ID. Therefore, if a student did not take a particular class, there will be a NULL value in the final result.

I tested this in Access using your sample data and it works on my machine.

Also as a note, it is poor practice to have a field called just `ID` in each table (e.g. in the Pupil table, `ID` becomes `PupilID`). This makes it much easier to use, and it self documents.

Comment: When I try: SELECT ps.Pupil_ID, ps.LastName, ps.Subject_ID, r.Grade
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Pupil.ID AS Pupil_ID, Pupil.LastName FROM Pupil LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT Subject.ID AS Subject_ID FROM Subject) ON 1=1) ps
        LEFT JOIN Report r ON r.PupilID = ps.Pupil_ID AND r.SubjectID = ps.Subject_ID
ORDER BY Pupil_ID, Subject_ID     I still get the error 'Join not supported'.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! If you do not have any more issues, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cross join pupil and subject tables and left join result to report table

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [cross join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm):

```
SELECT Pupil.ID, Pupil.LastName, SubjectID, Grade FROM
Pupil, Subject LEFT JOIN Report ON Subject.ID=Report.SubjectID
WHERE Subject.ID=1
```

Comment: Many thanks! My query is for an access database (mdb) and it won't accept the LEFT JOIN: SELECT Pupil.ID, Pupil.LastName, SubjectID, Grade FROM
Pupil, Subject LEFT JOIN Report ON Subject.ID=Report.SubjectID
WHERE Subject.ID=1         Is there a different way of writing this that an access database would accept?

Comment: Access supports left join, I think it is the implicit join that is causing problems here.

Comment: @Philip You may want to take a look of this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Join-data-sources-in-a-query-09c75798-8cc7-4877-a8a3-b39572400c19#__toc311116344

Comment: I've also tried:  select * from Pupil p,  (select * from Subject where id = 1) s
left join Report on SubjectID = s.id and PupilID = p.id;   In access this gives the error 'Join not supported'

Answer (score 0):

To combine every pupil with every (or with a particular) subject, use cross join; Then use left join to get the corresponding grades:

```
select *
from pupil p cross join (select * from subject where id = 1) s
left join report on subjectId = s.id and pupilId = p.id
```